# Linq Lambda : Getting last user updated with group of same user using group by and count?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I want to get last user updated with a linq lambda expression using group by and the count of the remaining users. I don't know how I can do that.

here is my data :

```
userid | name | datetime            | isdelete
1      | abc  | 16-03-2017 15:45:59 | 0
1      | abc  | 16-03-2017 12:45:10 | 0 
2      | xyz  | 16-03-2017 15:45:59 | 0
1      | abc  | 16-03-2017 10:40:59 | 0
```

I want the result to look like this:

```
userid | name | datetime            | count 
1      | abc  | 16-03-2017 15:45:59 |   3   
2      | xyz  | 16-03-2017 15:45:59 |   1
```

Here the `count` for `userid = 1` should be 3 as there are three records for that id in the table.

I have written this query, but it is getting **all** the records.

```
List<Users> UList = new List<Users>();
UList  = db.Users.Where(a => a.isdelete == false)
    .OrderByDescending(a => a.datetime)
    .Skip(skip)
    .Take(pageSize)
    .ToList();
```

Anyone know how I can get the data I want? Please let me know using linq lambda expression.

Comment: If you want to return users there's no way to return the counts, assuming that `User` doesn't have a property `Count`. You need to return DTOs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by user, than sort each group and take first from each group

```
var UList = (db.Users
                      .Where(a => a.isdelete == false)
                      .GroupBy(a => a.UserId)
                      .Select(g => new MyNewClass
                                   {
                                     Count = g.Count(), 
                                     User =  g.OrderByDescending(a => a.datetime).First()
                                   }
                      ))
                       .Skip(skip)
                       .Take(pageSize)
                       .ToList();
```

Comment: i think he also needs the count

Comment: hi i am adding this also in last .Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList(); then getting error after select().

Comment: this is not working even i am just add tolist() after select() getting error.

Comment: @Hiren, editted answer, check that if not send error message?

Comment: system.Argumentnullexpression like this "cannot implicitly convert type 'system.collections.generic.list anonymous type#1 ' to 'system.collections.generic.list<Users>"

Comment: can one of this fields be null? userid, isdelete, datetime, skip, pagesize?

Comment: ahh, right, sorry my fault, 1 sec will fix... the result of this query is not User list, if you want to convert it to users list, use another select... var will work

Comment: can you please edited your answer if you possible then please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138319/discussion-between-arsen-mkrtchyan-and-hiren).

Comment: suposse i don't use var then any other wave actully i have write many condition on UList list varible.

Comment: hi @Arsen Mkrtchyan can you please one help me?

Comment: on which question?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to group your data:

```
var result = db.Users.Where(a => !a.isdelete)
    .GroupBy(x => x.userid)
    .Select(x => new User 
        { 
            userid = x.Key, 
            name = x.Last().Name, 
            datetime = x.OrderByDescending(a => a.datetime).First().datetime, 
            count = x.Count() 
        });
```

EDIT: This might be not optimal considering the performance as the call to `Last` and `OrderByAscending` will both iterate the whole data. To overcome this a bit you may re-structure this query a bit:

```
var result = db.Users.Where(a => !a.isdelete)
    .GroupBy(x => x.userid)
    .Select(x => new 
        { 
            user = x.OrderByDescending(a => a.datetime).First(), 
            count = x.Count() 
        })
    .Select(x => new User {
        name = x.user.name,
        userid = x.user.userid,
        datetime = x.user.datetime,
        count = x.count
    });
```

Comment: interesting how generated SQL if we change x.Last() to x.First()

Comment: Doesn´t Linq2Sql know `Last`? I´m not sure. Anyway we could use `First` as well.

Comment: I believe it knows... I wonder if it will do two inner queries to get name and datetime...

Comment: @ArsenMkrtchyan I added an approach that uses one less iteration.